# Adding timestamps to HEVC with ffmpeg library, mismatch in timestamps when run with Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, gstreamer, codec

We are encoding sample frames using NvEncoder with HEVC. Since HEVC frames do not have any timestamps, in order to perform seek operation on the video, we wrote a remuxer in C++ that creates timestamps for the frames in an orderly fashion and writes the encoded frames in a video container (mp4,mov). The output video in mp4 container looks fine when played with ffplay, and timestamps seems correct when checked with ffprobe. However, when we try to play the video in Gstreamer pipeline, 2nd and 3rd frames seem to have the exactly same timestamp. So when the video is played, 3rd frame is skipped and 2nd frame is shown twice. We cannot tolerate any frame loss, so we need to solve this problem, which we think is due to an incompatibility between ffmpeg and gstreamer regarding frame timestamps. I can also provide the source-code of our remuxer and example outputs if that would help.

I used the following Gstreamer pipeline to play the mp4:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=5_fps.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink
```

Following  command  also gives the same mismatching frame timestamps:

```
ffmpeg -i 5_fps.bin -vcodec copy -acodec copy 5_fps.mp4
```

Many thanks!

Edit: I am adding the part of remuxer where each frame from the input stream is read and timestamps are added.

```
int frame_no=-1; //starting with -1 gives the same ffprobe results as command line ffmpeg container conversion, starting with 0 again causes the same timestamp problem    
while (1) {
AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;

_status = av_read_frame(_ifmt_ctx, &_pkt);
if (_status < 0) break;

in_stream  = _ifmt_ctx->streams[_pkt.stream_index];
if (_pkt.stream_index >= _stream_mapping_size ||
    _stream_mapping[_pkt.stream_index] < 0) {
  av_packet_unref(&_pkt);
  continue;
}
double inputFPS=av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);

double outputFPS=av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);

_pkt.stream_index = _stream_mapping[_pkt.stream_index];
out_stream = _ofmt_ctx->streams[_pkt.stream_index];
_pkt.pts=frame_no*in_stream->time_base.den/inputFPS;
_pkt.dts=_pkt.pts;
_pkt.duration = in_stream->time_base.den/inputFPS; 
_pkt.pos = -1;
std::cout<<"rescaled pts: "<<_pkt.pts<<" dts: "<<_pkt.dts<<" frame no: "<< frame_no<<std::endl;

std::cout<<"input time_base den: "<<in_stream->time_base.den<<" output time_base den: "<<out_stream->time_base.den<<std::endl;

frame_no++;
_status = av_interleaved_write_frame(_ofmt_ctx, &_pkt);
if (_status < 0) {
  cout<<"Error muxing packet\n";
  break;
}
av_packet_unref(&_pkt);}
```

I first tried this method where each frame timestamp (pts and dts) is incremented by packet duration. At first I thought this method would not work since B-frames are decoded in different order, so I first tried videos with no b-frames. However, when I tried with videos with b-frames, it again worked. I thought decoded frames would be in a different order, however that was not the case. The only issue is that only the second and third frames appear to have the same timestamps in Gstream (not in Ffmpeg), other than these two frames remaining video plays just fine. Overall, I am also confused that b-frames do not cause any frame order problem.

Example [encoded input](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RpgouYmin6IIcQf8WL1QdSnYv7LKRCYu/view?usp=sharing), example [output video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1irclGFjSnuFlKOhX6PSpdqY79-6rfBXR/view?usp=sharing) if you want to examine the frames. (I don't know if it's okay to share files over google drive, please correct me if there is a better way to share, or not.)

Comment: do you have b-frames? are you perhaps writing the timestamps in display order rather than decoder order? Some sort of [mre] would probably help

Comment: Thank you for your response @AlanBirtles, I added a code snippet and explain the issue with b-frames.

Comment: Setting the dts and pts to the same value for files with b frames is definitely incorrect

Comment: @AlanBirtles That also occured to me, however I would expect that setting b-frame pts values like that would cause a huge error, like an unplayable video or reordered frames. How can we still play the video smoothly with ffmpeg like that, does ffmpeg has a correction mechanism for wrong pts-dts values? But anyways, not allowing b-frames definitely solves the problem of wrong timestamp values on gstreamer side.

Comment: If you're just playing the file sequentially you don't need the timestamps at all, just feed all the frames in decoding order to the decoder and it'll give you back frames in display order. I'd guess therefore that ffmpeg is just ignoring the timestamps but gstreamer is trying to use them

Comment: @AlanBirtles That sounds very reasonable to me. I will try to set b-frame pts-dts values reasonably and see the results again. But for the time being, it seems that we will not use any b-frames at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @AlanBirtles mentioned, assigning timestamps of b-frames in my naive way is not correct at all. I assumed that since the video was playable, timestamp are somehow corrected by Ffmpeg or Gstreamer, and I did not relate my main problem to this. However, when I tried to convert container of a video with no b-frames, the problem of 3rd frame being lost is solved. So I understand that either set timestamps of b-frames correctly, or I should use videos without b-frames. Even though it is not the viable solution, for the time being we will not use b-frames, however in the future I will try to reimplement the remuxer so that any video is remuxed OK.